# syntax errors in a scheme search program

Tags: recursion, scheme

*"Define a function called search that takes a symbol and a list and returns the position of the first occurrence of the symbol in the list using zero based indexing. (If the first element of the list is equal to the symbol, return 0.) Only search the top level elements. If the list does not contain the symbol, return -1."*

I wrote a program like this but I get syntax errors. Can someone help me out please.

```
(define search (lambda (n x)
                 (let ( (i 0)))
                   (if (empty? x)
                    -1
                    (if (equal? n (car x))
                        0
                     (let ((index (+ i 1)) (tail (cdr x))))
                     (if (equal? n (search (n tail)))                       
                       index)))))
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code correctly. Use the <0101010> button to mark a section of text as code. You should also include the homework tag, as this is obviously a homework-related question. Use the "edit" link below your question to make the corrections.

Comment: Also include the errors the interpreter is giving you. We can't explain the cause of the errors if we don't know what the errors are.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have too many closing parentheses on this line:

```
             (let ( (i 0)))
```

Remove the last one, and try again. This is not the only syntax error in your code, so you will have to take care to make all the parentheses match up properly.

Comment: @dave: Why don't you ask him to fly to your town and do your assignment for you? He could also take out the garbage and do the dishes.